# How to pass arguments for a UIGestureRecognizer action

Tags: ios, iphone, textfield

I want to detect if my `UITextField` has been touched. I'm using this to detect touches:

```
[self.myTextField addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTapped)]];
```

and I have a method

```
- (void)textFieldTapped:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"is Tapped");
}
```

I want to add the `UITextField` as an argument using `@selector(textFieldTapped)` but I'm getting a error. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `UITextField` delegate methdos are already available. Why are you using `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Check out my answer @user2951348 for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.myTextField addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTapped:)]];
```

you missed colon at the end of the selector name.

EDIT: and the action should look like

```
-(void)textFieldTapped : (UIGestureRecognizer*)rec{
  NSLog(@"is Tapped");
}
```

Comment: This is the answer, but the parameter passed to the `textFieldTapped:` is not a `UITextField ` but `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: how can I get what textField is touch?

Comment: UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)rec.view;

Comment: Check out my answer @user2951348 for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The target action selector could take 1 arg which indicates the sender of this message. You can add a colon to send the message, but instead of getting a `UITextField` as the parameter, you can only get the sender (here it is the UITapGestureRecognizer) as the parameter. It would be like this:

[self.myTextField addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTapped:)]];

```
-(void)textFieldTapped : (UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr{
    NSLog(@"is Tapped");
}
```

If you want to know some detail about the text field, you can use the `view` property of the UITapGestureRecognizer

`UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)gr.view`

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to do little modification

```
[self.myTextField addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTapped:)]];
```

and method will be

```
-(void)textFieldTapped : (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UITextField *tappedTextField=(UITextField *)[[recognizer self] view]; // this is the textfield that is being tapped.
    //You can access all the property associated with the textField.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the error you're receiving is a result of not including the colon after `textFieldTapped` within `@selector(textFieldTapped)`, even with the colon, your code wouldn't work as expected.  This is because the `UIGestureRecognizer` action method only accepts the `UIGestureRecognizer` as an argument; and if you set the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s target as `@selector(textFieldTapped:)`, the `UIGestureRecognizer` itself is passed automatically as long the method indicates that it accepts it as an argument. Ex. (in the case of a `UITapGestureRecognizer`):

```
- (void)textFieldTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    NSLog(@"is Tapped");
}
```

Then to find out which `UITextField` has been touched, you can get the `UITextField` object within that `textFieldTapped:` method using:

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)gesture.view;
```

But in this particular case, it's unnecessary to create a gesture recognizer at all since there is already an appropriate `UITextField` delegate method to detect touches in the `UITextField`.  After adding the `UITextFieldDelegate` to the .h and setting `theParticularTextField.self = delegate` I suggest using:

```
// Called whenever a text field is selected as long as its delegate is set to self
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == theParticularTextField) {
        // Do whatever you want to do when that particular text field is tapped.
    }

    return YES;
}
```